# UWP Unable to debug .NET compilation code (Release)

Tags: debugging, crash, native, release, uwp

My UWP apps were running flawlessly on debug but instant crash on release, I've uploaded the package to app store twice and they tell me that my app doesn't work too. Unticking that .NET Native stuff helps but I'm not sure it will work on other users' pc and I have no idea what that does, I think something goes wrong.

My other projects can run Release build flawlessly, I've tried clean up everything and re-build but I get the same error.

Thank you

edit: tried running on my laptop, stuck at splashscreen then got the same error, I even tried removing anything on MainPage constructor and OnNavigatedTo.

Running flawlessly on debug but instant crash on release:
[image: Running flawlessly on debug but instant crash on release]

Unticking this helps:
[image: Unticking this helps]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution, I think this is a bug where Visual Studio passes command line to compiler which I suspect they forgot to put quote "" to cover the path.

### Project with spaces in path

[image: Project with spaces in path]

### Project without spaces in path

> Be aware that spaces must not exist neither in the **path to the project file** nor in the **Assembly name**.

[image: Project without spaces in path]

Comment: You're correct that this is caused by having spaces in your project name. We've diagnosed this to an issue with the .NET Native pdb writer but it's more or less as you describe. In fact, you should be able to launch an app with spaces in the name (CTRL+F5)... just not debug it. We're going to get this fixed for Update 2.

Comment: Oh, CTRL+F5 to simulate the one I will download from apps store.. thank you so much for that

Comment: Yep. You should also be able to launch it from the start menu.

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be able to run on .NET Native because it will be compiled that way in the store (before users are able to install it).

Release builds do have code optimizations enabled, which will make it harder to debug. If you want to debug .NET Native, you should disable the optimizations.

[image]

For the full guide on debugging .NET Native, check the [msdn article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps.aspx). I hope this helps in hunting down the actual problem (which can be plenty).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your recommendation. All my settings are on default and I actually just want to make the release build work so I find that unticking the compile with .NET native works, I'm not trying to debug release build, I just want to upload to apps store.. I will continue hunting the problem, thanks!